# Find only duplicate rows with sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to get only duplicates, meaning anything that is not the first entry with the lowest number.
A duplicate is defined as an entry that has the same values as another (In example 1, name,type,cats in example 2: petId, petName, petType).
Of those duplicates, it should only get the excess ones, meaning, all of the except the first.

For example:
Table:

```
name type cats number
carl two  meow  1
carl two  meow  2
carl bad  meow  1
carl bad  meow  3
carl two  pot   1
sven two  meow  2

What I want:
carl two  meow  2
carl bad  meow  3
```

I'm using sequelize to generate the queries with where clauses depending on user input, so it needs to retain that. Otherwise I could use a raw SQL Query(I believe anyway.) such as:

```
    WITH cte AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( 
                PARTITION BY PetId, PetName, PetType 
                ORDER BY PetId, PetName, PetType
                ) AS Row_Number
        FROM Pets
    )
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE Row_Number <> 1;
```

Which should turn this:

```
PetId  PetName  PetType
-----  -------  -------
1      Wag      Dog    
1      Wag      Dog    
2      Scratch  Cat    
3      Tweet    Bird   
4      Bark     Dog    
4      Bark     Dog    
4      Bark     Dog
```

into this:

```
PetId  PetName  PetType  Row_Number
-----  -------  -------  ----------
1      Wag      Dog      2         
4      Bark     Dog      2         
4      Bark     Dog      3   
(Explanation: Both those(4|bark|dog) records are in the output because there are 3 in the input and those two are duplicates and not the first. (1|scratch|Cat) and (3|tweet|bird) are not in the output because: they are not duplicates. In the case that you added another (1|scratch|Cat), (So that there is two) it should only show one, the later one.))
```

(from: https://database.guide/6-ways-to-select-duplicate-rows-in-sqlite/)

I have tried many, many things. Implementations with count and row number. but turning this SQL query into a sequelize seems impossible.

The reason I am trying to do this in a DB query is for both performance (There are too many rows to do it in a reasonable time frame in the program) and because it needs to work with other sequelize queries.

Comment: I don't believe that SQL query will get you that output. Furthemore, I don't undertsand how that output is generated from that data. Why doesn't your sample data and desired results columns match your sql? I feel like I've been given bad sample data and I'm left to guess what it *should* be.

Comment: The query is from here: https://database.guide/6-ways-to-select-duplicate-rows-in-sqlite/
It says that it does what I need "This returns just the excess rows from the matching duplicates. So if there are two identical rows, it returns one of them. If there are three identical rows, it returns two, and so on."

Comment: What do you consider a duplicate in your "Which should turn this:" sample data. Your output has three dogs, two barks, and two "4" ids. I don't understand what YOU think is a duplicate in this data. And your partitioning and ordering in `row_number()` is so wrong that it's not helping. Can you explain, in english, what you consider a duplicate and why?

Comment: Anything that has the same name, type and cats is a duplicate. Of those, I need to get only the duplicates for which one with a lower number exists. (which will be the first one)
The example query is not mine, are you saying it will not result in the output for it?
The names are arbitrary.

Comment: *"Anything that has the same name, type and cats is a duplicate"*. I dont understand what this means. "into this:" has two records with the same `name` and `type` (`4 | bark | dog | 3`). How are both of those records in the output? What does "cats" mean in regard to duplicates? You just don't want any record where `pettype='cat'`? What about tweet bird? Why isn't that in your output?

Comment: Both those(4|bark|dog) records are in the output because there are 3 in the input and those two are duplicates and not the first.
(1|scratch|Cat) and (3|tweet|bird) are not in the output because: they are not duplicates.
In the case that you added another (1|scratch|Cat), (So that there is two) it should only show one, the later one.

Comment: OH! Thank you. That makes sense. I need more coffee.

Comment: Oh I guess it is kind of hard to explain. I'll add more to the main post (: